# How do I output with join()?

Tags: python-3.x, ansible

I want to output strings with join().
How could I use this?

This is my code.

```
data_list = [{'A': 'a', 'B': 'b', 'C': 'c'}, {'A': 'a', 'B': 'b', 'C': 'c'}]

A_list = set()
for data in data_list:
    A = data['A']
    A_list.add(A)


for A in A_list:
    B_list = []
    C_list = []
    for data in data_list:
        if data['A'] == A:
            B = data['B']
            C = data['C']
            B_list.append(B)
            C_list.append(C)



    print('\n[{}]'.format(A))
    print('' + '\n' .join(B_list) + ' host=' + ' '.join(C_list))
```

Here's its outputs.

```
[a]
b
b host=c c

[a]
b
b host=c c
```

But I want to get the result as below.

```
[a]
b host=c
b host=c 

[A]
b host=c
b host=c
```

I thought if I create list of 'host' as much as 'B' so I can use join() to insert 'host' but actual data is much more than the above and I'm not sure how much variables in these each dictionaries.

Any ideas?

In addition, this output will be used in ansible inventory file.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be clearer what is happening if you print the `repr` of the `'' + '\n' .join(B_list) + ' host=' + ' '.join(C_list)` rather than printing it directly. You get

```
'b\nb host=c c'
```

So that is joining the two elements of `B_list` with a `"\n"` between them, and then inserting `" host="`, and then joining the two element of `C_list` with a `" "` between them. When you print it, the `"\n"` turns into a newline and you can see the output you're getting.

To get the output you desire, you will need to match up the *pairs* of B's and C's. You can do this with [tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple):

```
# ... before this loop is the same... 
for A in A_list:
    BC_list = []
    for data in data_list:
        if data['A'] == A:
            # note, you're inserting B and C into the same element in the list
            BC_list.append( (data['B'], data['C']) )

    print('\n[{}]'.format(A))
    # now you can unpack the tuple
    for b, c in BC_list:
        print(b + ' host=' + c)
```

There are cleaner ways to write this with fewer loops, like with [list comprehensions](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_list_comprehension.php) but this should get you closer to a solution.

Comment: As a side note, the values for `A` `B` and `C` from your example (or `A`, `b` and `c` in mine) are all the _values_ from the `data_list` dictionary. All of the values you gave are lowercase, but your desired output has uppercase letters. A clearer example might use more distinct key/value pairs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I wanted to retrieve B and C 's values associated with key A so [('b', 'c'), ('b', 'c')] this type is fitted for in this situation.
Like A is a place and B is a node name so A and B is must be associated when these are extracted from each dictionaries.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need join? Cant you just use:

```
print(B_list[0]+' host='+C_list[0])
```

This will output:

```
b host=c
```

Which is not uppercase b and c as you requested but can be made so by modifying the original `B_list` and `C_list`.

---

Extracting multiple lines:

```
for x in range(len(B_list)):
    print(B_list[x]+' host='+C_list[x])
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I want to extract lowercase so you are right. But your code can output only one 
'b host=c'. It must be extracted multiple lines like I already wrote above.

Comment: @zadop Thank you for editing. Now 'for' is effective in this case. join() method cannot to output each index instead of output all of indexes at once.